# With same code different view on emulator and device

Tags: android, tabs

Now please suggest what would be wrong with device that its showing different colors on tabs as that of emulator. I want it exactly same as emulator. If anyone wants my code to be attached then please suggest it.

Comment: post your xml files please..

Comment: I would assume that the device and emulator are running different versions of Android and that it is the difference in the default themes that you are seeing. You can explicitly define a theme but be aware that each major API version has its own common theme. A KitKat theme would look very out of place on a HoneyComb device and vice versa.

Comment: I just have issue with tab color. I want it to be yellow and i also succeed in doing it.But device doesn't accept it. I don't think it is becuase of xml. All Layout are working fine. Even if you need it which  one you want only this fragment or its activity.

Comment: I used min api as api14 and Target as Api17

Comment: @indivisible So what you suggest me to do..Because emulator design is to be followed. So what i could do to get same view in device

Comment: My comment got a bit long, I'll post it as an answer in a second...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the device and emulator are running different versions of the Android API and that it is the difference in the default themes that you are seeing.
You can explicitly define a theme but be aware that each major API version has its own common theme aspects to keep the UI experience similar between apps to make it easier and more intuitive for a user to use and navigate around.

A KitKat theme would look very out of place on a HoneyComb device and vice versa.
In general the Android design guidelines will strongly discourage you from diverting too far from the default theme as it can very much ruin the "flow" between apps and make for some shocking transitions.

In the past there have been many apps that have just recreated their IOS themes when porting across to Android and these (lazy) implementations have been proven to be less appealing to users and the apps suffer because of it`*`. I don't know if it could be more attributed to the drastically different theme or the non-intuitive navigation (to an android user) that would be more to blame there. Perhaps a combination.

With all that said, [this Android resource on Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) would be a good place to start on doing it right.

You can inherit the default Style as defined by the device and its API then override just the aspects you choose to so that you won't have to create a full theme from the ground up.
This has the benefit of letting the OS still style most of the views/components according to its look (things like RadioButtons, CheckBoxes, etc) but let you tweak things slightly (or drastically) to keep the overall feel of your app the same across API versions, OS implementations and devices.

It will be your decision on how much you choose to change and which API version you want your app to try to be most like/emulate if one at all.

`*` (I don't have time to find a source for that but if I remember, I'll go hunting later (or perhaps a nice user will happen along and supply one?)).